# Automatically Create a Latex Invoice

Tags: automation

I've just set up a website with much help from the Stack forums!
I have customers who buy items (through the PayPal interface that takes care of the credit card payments).

I have made invoices in LaTex, which I edit manually. The next step I want to take, is to learn how to get my website to pass the purchase information into my LaTex document so that the invoice is automatically generated, and automatically send a copy to the customer.

Is there a LaTex API that would allow me to do something like this?

Comment: [Package invoice2](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/invoice2/invoice2.pdf) perhaps?

Comment: Related: [Building Your Own Invoice using `longtable` and `datatool`](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/custominvoice.shtml).

Comment: The DIY approach would be to have your website create a `info.tex` file that your `invoice.tex` template then `\input`s.

Answer (score 0):

Try [DynamicDocs API](https://advicement.io/dynamic-documents-api) by [ADVICEment](https://advicement.io/). DynamicDocs is JSON to PDF API, which uses LaTeX to compile PDFs. It lets you write [LaTeX templates](https://advicement.io/dynamic-documents-api/latex-template-examples) and merge JSON data into them. It also provides a library of [JSON to PDF](https://advicement.io/dynamic-documents-api/json-to-pdf-templates) templates.

Since you already have a tex file you want to use, you can use [Tex to PDF with pdfLaTeX template](https://advicement.io/dynamic-documents-api/json-to-pdf-templates/pub-tex-to-pdf-with-pdflatex-v1), with which you can pass your tex file as JSON payload and receive back the compiled pdf. For examples of how to call DynamicDocs API, visit the [DynamicDocs Public Collection](https://www.postman.com/advicement/workspace/dynamicdocs-api-public-workspace/overview) on the postman API network.

Disclaimer: I am involved in developing DynamicDocs API.